# Using iPhone touch & drag interface for intuitive List creation

Tags: iphone, user-interface, sdk

1) I want to create a List by touch and dragging icons from a Master List.
2) Also have the ability to Delete items in this newly created List or Rearrange their order.

Is there some code sample one could look at or possible design pointers on cleanly  accomplish this functionality.

I realize UITableView could accomplish this. But doing it visually in a single screenful is intuitive as it maintains the overall context of the task at hand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

None of the API UI classes will let you do this. Both tableviews and scrollviews want the entire screen. You're going to have to write a lot of stuff from scratch.

I think you will find that a dual list design is a poor interface choice. You really don't have room on an iPhone screen to display and manipulate two list within the same view. Remember as well that you won't be able to see all of both list if they run off the screen (which is likely.)

"Intuitive" is just marketing speak for "familiar". There is nothing intuitive about a nonstandard interface. Since iPhone users don't routinely drag items between list it will not be readily apparent to them how to work the interface. You will most likely be better off with a single master table in which users can check individual cells to be added to a sub list. This is a common interface on the iPhone and therefore more "intuitive".

Before spending a lot of time on this, I suggest you do a mockup that will display on the device itself. You can simply draw mock interface in a graphics program and then display it as an image in an imageview. This will let you test if you can display enough information in dual list to be useful and whether you can hit elements in both list reliably.

Comment: Thanks TechZen. In hindsight I do agree with you.